# How to avoid problems when saving edits in Geopackages from QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, geopackage

I really like working with Geopackages as the data format in QGIS. Only one file per layer and no limits on the namin of attributes.

But from time to time after editing a Geopackage I get the error message that the edits cannot be saved.

As latest example I tried just to rename an attribute and got this error:

Could not commit changes to layer Aktiviteter-Aarhus Kommune — Aktiviteter

Errors: ERROR: 2 attributes not renamed

Provider errors:
OGR error renaming field 1: sqlite3_exec(ALTER TABLE "Aktiviteter" RENAME COLUMN "ANTAL_ENHEDER" TO "Boliger") failed: no such column: ""ANTAL_ENHEDER""

I use the layer properties window to do the renaming:
[Layer Properties - Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUHvV.png)

Any recommandations when editing Geopackages?

Comment: How do you save the edits? Can you share the code involved, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: I just press the yellow pencil in the properties - Fields window. 

I ended up copying the geopackage from the file server it were on to my C-drive. And then I could do the renaming edits.

Comment: The geopackage is not well designed for editing. It is a proprietary format with different system tables hiding in sqlite. You are much better off using spatialite that is fully supported. It is still in sqlite, but with different system tables and better tools. I see the latest spatialite module which is used to extend sqlite to handle spatial tables now has a special virtual table to handle geopackage system tables. You need to be careful editing any schema in sqlite. There are a lot of limitations on what you are allowed to do. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html.

Comment: Whatever database you are using, trying to change the schema while you have the table open for reading, let alone writing will not be successful. I would save all edits, stop editing, remove the layer from the browser and make sure everything is closed first.